# How to cy.get from a select form that has no id or class

Tags: cypress

How do I use `cy.get(?).select('2')` if I have no class or id ?

```html
<select name="register[personal][birthday][month]">
<option value> Month </option>
<option value="1"> 1 </option>
<option value="2"> 2 </option>
<option value="3"> 3 </option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following based on name and then find the option by index `eq(2)`to get the second option. Here `eq(0) is Month`, `eq(1) is 1`, `eq(2) is 2` and so on.

```
cy.get('select[name="register[personal][birthday][month]"] > option')
      .eq(2) 
      .click()
```

You could try another one based on value:

```
cy.get('select[name="register[personal][birthday][month]').then(function($select){
   $select.val('2');
 })
```

Comment: The second one worked perfectly! This should be added to official cypress documentation :) Thank you

Comment: In the first option, try removing ‘>option’ from the get() method and give a try